# How do I rename XML values using php?

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

How do I rename a value in xml using PHP? This is what I've got so far:

```
<?php
$q = $_GET["q"];
$q = stripslashes($q);

$q = explode('|^', $q);

$old = $q[0];

$dom                     = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput       = true;

$dom->Load("test.xml");

$xpath   = new DOMXPath($dom);    
$query1  = 'channel/item[title="' . $old . '"]/title';
$entries = $xpath->query($query1);

foreach ($entries as $entry) 
{        
    $oldchapter = $entry->parentNode->removeChild($entry);

    $item       = $dom->getElementsByTagName('item');

    foreach ($item as $items) 
    {
        $title = $dom->createElement('title', $q[1]);            
        $items->appendChild($title);            
    }
}    

$dom->save("test.xml");
```

Basically, what it does is take two titles from a url, the old existing title, and the one the user wants to change it to (so like this `oldtitle|^newtitle`), and puts them into an array.

What I've tried doing is removing the existing old title, and then making a new title with, using the new title value from the url, but it doesn't seem to be working. Where am I going wrong, or is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: seems like you're setting `$dom->preserveWhiteSpace` four times, when only the first should be necessary...

Comment: @FrankFarmer sorry about that, fixed it. Is there any way though I can go about achieving this?

Comment: @looserlf: Check your code again, I made some corrections. Most of these settings you can only set *once* and the belong before doing `load()` (this is not totally precise but it should give you a good guide at the start until you have read bout those properties in the manual and understood what they do).

Comment: Also your question is not clear. Node-values in XML are *set* not *renamed*. You can rename element-names or attributes (although you don't rename them but you replace them with a differently named node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is with [`DOMNode::replaceChild()`](http://php.net/domnode.replacechild). The majority of your code is correct, you've just slightly over-complicated some of the DOM stuff.

Try this:

```
<?php

    $q = $_GET["q"];
    $q = stripslashes($q);

    $q = explode('|^', $q);

    $old = $q[0];

    $dom                     = new DOMDocument;

    // Do this *before* loading the document
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput       = true;

    $dom->Load("test.xml");
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

    $query1  = 'channel/item[title="' . $old . '"]/title';
    $entries = $xpath->query($query1);

    // This is all you need to do in the loop
    foreach ($entries as $oldTitle) {
        $newTitle = $dom->createElement('title', $q[1]);
        $entry->parentNode->replaceChild($newTitle, $oldTitle);
    }

    $dom->save("test.xml");
```